# How can i decrease the distance between two script editor?

Tags: script-webpart

I have got two banners in my home page. But there is more distance between two banners. I want them be more closer.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.ms-webpartPage-root

{

border-spacing: 0px !important;

}

.ms-webpartzone-cell

{

margin: 0px !important;

}

</style>   try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style type="text/css">                                                   
       .ms-webpartPage-root { border-spacing: 0px !important; }                                                             
       .ms-webpartzone-cell { margin: 0px !important; }                
 </style>                                                                                                   //try this
```